# does a small variation in the constants of a power series result in a small variation in its radius of convergence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, continuity, metric-spaces, epsilon-delta

in $cs$, the space of all sequences $(a_n)$ such that the series ${\displaystyle \sum _{i=1}^{\infty }a_{n}}$
is convergent (possibly conditionally), the norm of a sequence is defined as ${\displaystyle \left\|(x_n)\right\|_{cs}=\sup _{n}\left|\sum _{i=1}^{n}x_{i}\right|}$. for $(a_n)\in cs$ we can also talk about an induced radius ${}_i{r}((a_n))$ defined as the radius of convergence for $\displaystyle \sum _{i=1}^{\infty }a_{n}x^n$ which is given by ${}_ir((a_n)) = \frac{1}{\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}{|a_n|^{\frac{1}{n}}}}$. My question then is whether the induced radius is a continuous function where it is a real number, that is if we know ${}_i{r}((a_n)) \in \mathbb{R}$

$$\forall \epsilon>0 \stackrel{?}{\exists} \delta>0 \ (\displaystyle \left\|(h_n)\right\|_{cs}<\delta \Rightarrow |{}_i{r}((a_n+h_n))-{}_i{r}((a_n))|<\epsilon)$$
sommewhat helpful source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bs_space

Comment: alright, I'll add a quick edit

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro $r(a) = 1/ \limsup \lvert a_n \rvert^{1/n}$.

Comment: @PaulFrost: That's it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This result does not seem to hold. As a counter example I choose for a given $\delta>0$

1. Sequence $(a_n)$ as $a_n = 3^{-n}$.
2. Sequence $(h_n)$ as $h_n = (-1)^n\delta$.

Note that $\|(h_n)\|\le\delta$ and using the comments we have $r((a_n)) = 3$. However, when we look at $r((a_n+h_n))$ we see that
\begin{align}
r((a_n+h_n)) &= \left(\limsup_{n\to\infty}|3^{-n}+(-1)^n\delta|^{\frac{1}{n}}\right)^{-1} \\
&=  \left(\limsup_{n\to\infty}|\delta|^{\frac{1}{n}}\right)^{-1} \\
&= 1. 
\end{align}
It follows that we have $r((a_n+h_n)) - r((a_n)) = 2$, regardless of the $\delta$ chosen.

Comment: The series $\sum h_n$ is not convergent.

Comment: @Alosapien Is $(h_n)$ required to be in $cs$ in your OP?

Comment: Ah my mistake, I did not realise that $(h_n)$ might have to be an element of $cs$. If we want $(h_n)$ to be convergent, then $h_n = \delta\frac{6}{\pi^2}\frac{1}{n^2}$ should be a counter example along the same lines.

Comment: $h_n$  must be in $cs$, though I should have been clear about that

Comment: I'm still having trouble seeing how $(\limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty} |3^{−n}+(−1)^{n}\delta |^{\frac{1}{n}})^{−1}=(\limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty} |(−1)^{n}\delta |^{\frac{1}{n}})^{−1}$, or how that would hold up with the new $(h_n)$.